# Increase the contrast in Z scale

Tags: plotting, color

I use the following code to plot my 2D map. I would like to increase the contrast in Z scale in order to see better the details in the blue area (-0.5 to 0) and red area (0.5 to 1) better and put in white all the data between 0 and 0.5. I don't see how to do it (I tried `RegionFunction`). In attached the picture I get and the data can be found [here](https://share.orange.fr/#A8h4VyTRUw3109d09b6b) or [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/wtmYN1Rb).

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
file = FileNames["*.dat", NotebookDirectory[]];
func[file_String /; FileExistsQ[file]] := 
 Module[{data, dataT}, data = Import[file, "Table", HeaderLines -> 2];
   dataT = Transpose[data];
  dataT = {dataT[[1]]*10, dataT[[2]]*10, 
    dataT[[3]]}; (*je converti de angtroms a nano*)

  dataT[[3]] = Rescale[dataT[[3]], MinMax[dataT[[3]]], {-1., 1.}];
  data = Transpose[dataT];

  graph = ListDensityPlot[data,
    PlotLabel -> FileBaseName[file],
    PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 0.5}, {-0.5, 0.5}, {-1., 1.}}, 
    ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {-0.8, 0.8}}])]

  ]

func /@ file
```

[image]

Comment: Does this match your color range? `myTemperatureMap[f_] := Blend[{{0., Blue}, {.25, Lighter@LightBlue}, {.25, White}, {.75,White}, {.75, Yellow}, {1., Red}}, f]` ... I tried it, but the results are exaggerated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Blend` to define a color gradient.

```
myTemperatureMap[f_] := 
 Blend[{{0., Blue}, {.25, Lighter@LightBlue}, {.25, White}, {.75, 
    White}, {.75, Yellow}, {1., Red}}, f]
```

Compare `myTemperatureMap` to the named color gradient, `"TemperatureMap"`.

```
LinearGradientImage[myTemperatureMap, {200, 20}, DataRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image: myTemperatureMap]

```
LinearGradientImage["TemperatureMap", {200, 20}, DataRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image: TemperatureMap]

Here are `myTemperatureMap` and `"TemperatureMap"` applied to a density plot:

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 ColorFunction -> myTemperatureMap, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: density plot with myTemperatureMap]

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: density plot with "TemperatureMap"]

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot, I get to the same conclusion. Your way to include `Blend` in a function `myTemperatureMap` is more nice compare to what I wrote (not shown)

Answer (score 1):

```
cf1 = If[Abs[#] <= .5, White, ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {-1, 1}}][#]] &; 

cf2 = Blend[Join[{#, ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {-1, 0}}][#]} & /@ Range[-1, -.5, .1], 
  {{-.5, White}, {.5, White}},
  {#, ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 1}}][#]} & /@ Range[.5, 1., .1]], #] &;
```

Using the example in creidhne's answer:

```
dp = DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 300, PlotPoints -> 200, 
  MaxRecursion -> 5, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{-.5, .5}}, 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"];

{dpcf1, dpcf2} = DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
    PlotPoints -> 200,  MaxRecursion -> 5, ImageSize -> 400, PlotLegends -> Automatic,
    MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{-.5, .5}},
    ColorFunction -> #, ColorFunctionScaling -> False] & /@ {cf1, cf2};

Row[{dp, dpcf1, dpcf2}]
```

[image]

You can get the same result for the main plot using `cf1` or using `RegionFunction` but the legend is not affected by the `RegionFunction` setting:

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 300, PlotPoints -> 200, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
 RegionFunction -> (Abs[#3] >= .5 &), 
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thin, Gray]]
```

[image]